# Trying to display output of Stored Procedure in console

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

Hello I'm having trouble displaying the output of a SP in a console window using C#. Here is the SP code first then the C# after that.

(SP code (Updated with SP code))

```
- GetDepartmentName stored procedure.
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
        WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[GetDepartmentName]') 
        AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
 BEGIN
 EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDepartmentName]
  @ID int,
  @Name nvarchar(50) OUTPUT
  AS
  SELECT @Name = Name FROM Department
  WHERE DepartmentID = @ID
   '
   END
   GO
```

(c# code)

```
     public void RunStoredProcParams()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = null;
            SqlDataReader rdr = null;

            int ID = 1;
            //string Name = ""; Tried testing with this 

            try
            {
                conn = new
                SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=School;Integrated Security=SSPI");
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetDepartmentName", conn);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", ID));

                //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", Name));  Tried testing 
    //with this. Don't get output when added, get error message when commented out.

                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Department: {0}", rdr["Name"]);

                }

            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
                if (rdr != null)
                {
                    rdr.Close();
                }
            }
        }

    }


 //cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", Name));
```

I added this line above because I keep getting error message ""Procedure or function 'GetDepartmentName' expects parameter '@Name', which was not supplied." Without an input, I get an error message even though this is suppose to output the results..

Comment: Please include your actual stored procedure code.  All you've done is show how to call it from SQL or C#, not the proc itself

Comment: SP code? I'm pretty sure the top part of my post is the code unless I'm mistaken

Comment: You are mistaken, that's an EXEC statement, i.e. a statement that will execute a stored procedure.  The stored procedure would begin, `CREATE PROCEDURE`...

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I added the SP code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add that parameter to the command like you did with id

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name"){Direction = Output});
```

After you execute the command, you can get the value from

```
cmd.Parameters["@Name"]
```

Ok try this then

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetDepartmentName", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = _ID });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Size = 50, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    _Name = cmd.Parameters["@Nume"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Sorry but could you explain it more? I tried adding {Direction = Output}, that gave me an error message so added Direction = ParameterDirection.Output and that fixed it then SqlParameter("@Name") wanted an input so I gave it an empty string but still nothing output onto the console using string RetVal = cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("output: {0}", RetVal);. If the SP output the results, why does it need an input?

Comment: I'm sorry but your proc Getstudentgrades doesn't have a parameter named @Name, maybe you put the wrong SP?

Comment: Sorry been out of the house, I'll be home tonight to test it out, thanks!

Comment: Ok cool, got home from work and tried this out. I don't know what to say after trying all sorts of solutions but I'm glad this works. Thanks!